# man sections

Tags: manpage

How do I access specific sections of man pages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put the section number in front of the item you want to reference. For example, to access the sysctl function from the library section, you can write:

```
man 3 sysctl
```

and to access the sysctl tool from the system administrator's section, you would write:

```
man 8 sysctl
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to what [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270677/man-sections#270694) said: if you're not sure what section something is in, you can also see *all* of the man pages for a given topic by typing

```
man -a topic
```

This is useful for topics such as `printf`, for which there is both a command and a C function that do similar things.

Comment: the apropos flga will only work on systems after catman has been run

Comment: I think the -a flag just lists entries for a specific item in all the sections... to emulate apropos I think you use the -k flag...

Answer (score 0):

use the -s flag, for example:

```
man -s 2 read
```

you might like to look at

```
man intro
```

to get an idea of what's where.

HTH.

cheers,

Rob

Comment: 'man -s N' is Unix Sys V (if not SVR4) style - and supported by POSIX, but not supported by Linux (nor, I think, MacOS X).